# split pandas column into many using delimiter from right to left

Tags: python, pandas

The following code splits a column into two for example if I have the following string `"hi.this.is.an.example"` i will get separate columns for `"hi"` and `"this"`.

This splits the string going from the left to right however, I want to go from right to left instead so would want `"example"` and `"an"`

```
df['variable'].str.split('.', 2, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in pure python, use [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable': ["hi.this.is.an.example"]})

df['variable'].str.rsplit('.', 2, expand=True)
```

output:

```
            0   1        2
0  hi.this.is  an  example
```